# Can you return the document ID for a document that was just added into the collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to return to documentID so that I can store it and use it for later. I tried to store the return value of the createPrescription into a dynamic type, but i get and error too.

```
await DatabaseService().createPrescription(date, ic, illness, medication, important);

Future createPrescription(String newdate, String patientid, String sickness, String meds, String notes) async {
  return await prescriptionCollection.document().setData({
  'date' : newdate,
  'patientID' : patientid,
  'illness' : sickness,
  'medication' : meds,
  'important' : notes
});
```

}

Comment: Where are you storing it in your code? What is the error?

Comment: I did this cause I thought it return the document ID.
dynamic result = await DatabaseService().createPrescription(date, ic, illness, medication, important);

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `await prescriptionCollection.document().setData()` because you are not providing any id for the document().

If you want Firestore to generate an Id for you, you should do instead `await prescriptionCollection.add()` which returns a reference to the created document which has the generated id

You can do something like this:

```
Future createPrescription(String newdate, String patientid, String sickness,
    String meds, String notes) async {
  var _ref = await prescriptionCollection.add({
    'date': newdate,
    'patientID': patientid,
    'illness': sickness,
    'medication': meds,
    'important': notes
  });
  print(_ref.documentId);
}
```